# Validate string based on custom format

Tags: c#, regex, string, validation, format

I want to validate a string based on a custom format: `___.___` or `___,___`, 3 numbers followed by a dot or comma followed by 3 numbers (e.g. 123.456 or 123,456).

Currently, I have following code:

```
string InputText = "123.456"
bool result, result1, result2;
int test, test2;
result = Int32.TryParse(InputText.Substring(0, 3), out test);
result1 = (InputText[3] == '.' || InputText[3] == ',') ? true : false;
result2 = Int32.TryParse(InputText.Substring(4, 3), out test2);

if (result == false || result1 == false || result2 == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error! Wrong format.");
}
```

This works just fine, however, this seems rather inefficient and unnecessarily complex; is there an alternative to this?

Comment: have you tried `\d{3}[.,]\d{3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern to validate 3 numbers followed by a dot or comma followed by 3 numbers is,

```
^\d{3}[,.]\d{3}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zJ8eB3/1)

Answer (score 2):

Is there an alternative to this? Yes you can use [**`Regex.IsMatch`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this.

```
String s = "123.456";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d{3}[.,]\d{3}$")) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error! Wrong format.");
}
```

**Explanation**:

```
^        # the beginning of the string
 \d{3}   #   digits (0-9) (3 times)
 [.,]    #   any character of: '.', ','
 \d{3}   #   digits (0-9) (3 times)
$        # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

Aditional to Avinash answer if you want to capture the numbers matching the format you can use the following regex:

```
\b(\d{3}[.,]\d{3})\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/aD9tI0/3)**

[image]

Comment: While validating a string, it's better to give start and end patterns. Is screen-shot necessary?

Comment: @AvinashRaj you are totally right, I missed the part of "I want to validate" though about if a string matches the regex